# copying cv::cuda::GpuMat into another cv::cuda::GpuMat with roi

Tags: c++, opencv

I have

```
cv::Mat image, canvasImage ; 
cv::Rect roi;
```

With normal cv::Mat i can do following:

```
cv::Mat copyDestination = canvasImage(roi);

image.copyTo(copyDestination).
```

In the end what I get : a canvasImage with image inside roi.

Can I do the same with cv::cuda::GpuMat?
I tried to do the same with cv::cuda::GpuMat, but it seems that I get a pointer to a copy instead of pointer to memory, where I want to copy.

Comment: there's a copyTo and a copy constructor. pick whatever you like... https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#af1fd1025a62d333c9c970ca3761a23db